# Would a dedicated Celery server double the fetch time to a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance, celery

Considering this:

- You have a Web Server
- You have a separate Celery server (or another task broker)
- You have MySQL installed on a third server

So your Web Server talks to the Celery server, which talks to the MySQL server.

If you have a query with a high fetch time (say 10 seconds, 200K rows.), would it actually take 20 seconds to send it back to the Web Server? (10 for Web to Celery server, then 10 from Celery to the Web Server?

(My problem is that I`m looking at a query that takes 5-ish seconds to run, but about 18 seconds to reach the web server)

Comment: I'm not really sure what help you expect from us here. You can test the fetch time for any mysql query from your web server. If that's a lot faster than through celery, then you need to debug where the additional latency comes in.

Comment: What is the query?  Where, geographically, are the servers?  What does Celery do, go crunch?

Comment: @Shadow You`re right, I`ll try to query directly to the MySQL Server from the Webserver, see how much latency is added.

Comment: @RickJames It's a SELECT FROM blog_posts WHERE creation_date BETWEEN X and Y. The servers are right besides besides each other in our server room. That`s why I`m wondering if there Fetching time would be doubled (Once for MySQL, the second from Celery to the Web Server)... my guess was there would be no transportation latency.
Celery is an async task queue management application. So I send it 100 mySQL requests, it puts them in a queue and dispatches them to individual cores and whatnot depending on how many I`ve configured.

Comment: @Bedo - "Don't queue it, just do it."  -- You may have encountered a flaw that, _in some case_, leads queuing mechanisms to be counter-productive.  Does Celery provide any metrics on how well it dispatches the queued items?

Comment: @Bedo - Another _possible_ answer:  When SQL processing is chopped up into little tasks, the net effect _may_ be a slowdown.  For example, 100 single-row `INSERTs` is 10 times as slow as a single 100-row batch insert.